# Filter dataframe efficiently in R shiny by values in several columns

Tags: r, algorithm, shiny

I would like to know an efficient way to do the following. Having a reactive `dataframe()` in a shiny app. I want to have two reactive inputs (each with 2 possibilities `TRUE` or `FALSE`), which subset the rows based on the value in two columns, respectively. If I have only one input (and one column `photos`), I do something like:

```
df<-reactive({
  df<-mydf
  if(input$myinput==FALSE)
  {
    df<-df[!df$photos=="",]
  }
  else{
    df
  }
})
```

Problem is if I have two (or more) inputs (and columns), the code will grow too much if I use nested `if` and `else` inside the `if` and `else` above in the example, to allow for the 4 possibilities of two `TRUE/FALSE` inputs.

EDIT: Reproducible, make second input work without too much `if` and `else`:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) { 
  df<-reactive({
    df<-iris
    if(input$Petalw==T)
    {
      df<-df[df$Petal.Width==0.2,]
    }
    else{
      df
    }
  }) 
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(
    DT::datatable(df(), options = list(searching = FALSE,pageLength = 25))
  )
}
ui <- navbarPage(
  title = 'Select values in two columns based on two inputs respectively',
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 3,
           checkboxInput("Petalw","PetalWithIs0.2",T),
           checkboxInput("PetalL","PetalLengthis1.4",T)
    ),
    column(9,
  tabPanel('Table',       DT::dataTableOutput('table'))
  )
  )
)
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Please provide a small reproducible example.  Try with `switch`

Comment: Why not use a `selectInput` instead and have the choices set to unique values of the desired column and subset `df` accordingly?

Comment: Yes I get that. What I'm asking is why do you want to use `checkboxInput` for this? It can be done in a simpler way using something like a `selectInput`.

Comment: thanks for editing to make it reproducible. selectInput is also possible, for a checkboxinput see the answer below,..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could access the inputs via `input[[inputName]]` where inputName is the name of your input (e.g. "Sepal.Length-7.9").
Then you can check all inputs via

```
if(input[[inputName]]){
   split <- strsplit(inputName, "-")[[1]]
   name <- split[1]
   treshold <- as.numeric(split[2])
   global$filter[, inputName ==colnames(filter)] <- iris[name] == treshold
}else{
   global$filter[, inputName ==colnames(filter)] = TRUE
}
```

Inputs you can create with `renderUI()`:

```
output$checkBoxes <- renderUI({
    lapply(inputNames, function(inputName) checkboxInput(inputName, inputName, FALSE))
  })
```

In the example i use the maximum of all numerical columns.

Full code would read:

```
restr <- apply(iris, 2, max)[1:4]
inputNames <- paste(names(restr), restr, sep = "-") 
filter = sapply(inputNames, function(inputName) c(inputName = return(rep(TRUE, dim(iris)[1]))))


server <- function(input, output, session) { 
  global <- reactiveValues(filter = filter)

  df <- reactive({
      for(inputName in inputNames){
        if(!is.null(input[[inputName]])){
          isolate({
            if(input[[inputName]]){
              split <- strsplit(inputName, "-")[[1]]
              name <- split[1]
              treshold <- as.numeric(split[2])
              global$filter[, inputName ==colnames(filter)] <- iris[name] == treshold
            }else{
              global$filter[, inputName ==colnames(filter)] = TRUE
            }
          })
        }
      }
      iris[rowSums(global$filter) == 4, ]
    })


  output$checkBoxes <- renderUI({
    lapply(inputNames, function(inputName) checkboxInput(inputName, inputName, FALSE))
  })

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(
    DT::datatable(df(), options = list(searching = FALSE,pageLength = 25))
  )
}
ui <- navbarPage(
  title = 'Select values in two columns based on two inputs respectively',
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 3,
           uiOutput("checkBoxes")
    ),
    column(9,
           tabPanel('Table', DT::dataTableOutput('table'))
    )
  )
)
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can let the user select a value for one column, subset your data based on that value and then use `renderUI` and to generate dynamic `selectInput` drop downs with values from other columns.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) { 
  df <- reactive({
    subset(iris, Petal.Width == input$Petalw)
  })

  # Extract list of Petal Lengths from selected data - to be used as a filter
  p.lengths <- reactive({
    unique(df()$Petal.Length)
  })

  # Filter based on Petal Length
  output$PetalL <- renderUI({
    selectInput("PetalLengthSelector", "PetalLength", as.list(p.lengths()))
  })

  # Subset this data based on the values selected by user
  df_1 <- reactive({
    foo <- subset(df(), Petal.Length == input$PetalLengthSelector)
    return(foo)
  })

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(
    DT::datatable(df_1(), options = list(searching = FALSE,pageLength = 25))
  )
}
ui <- navbarPage(
  title = 'Select values in two columns based on two inputs respectively',
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 3,
           selectInput("Petalw","PetalWidth", choices = unique(iris$Petal.Width)),
           uiOutput("PetalL")
    ),
    column(9,
           tabPanel('Table', DT::dataTableOutput('table'))
    )
  )
)
shinyApp(ui, server)
```